# UnityCache Failed to load 'Build/Game.data.br' from indexedDB cache due to the error: RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, nginx, webgl, unity-webgl

I'm building Unity Game with Web3 Components like metamask connect. Things are working fine on local. But when I hosted it on server i got this error on page load.

> [UnityCache] Failed to load 'https://webgame.com/Build/Game.data.br' from indexedDB cache due to the error: RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed

However on network tab the file Game.data.br continuously gets downloaded until it is finished.

I've hosted it on Ubuntu Server with Nginx using following configuration https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-server-configuration-code-samples.html

The file size of Game.data.br is 550MB.

Comment: Try to build without compressions and check the size of "Game.data" file. You may have exceeded the 4 GB allowable RAM for a web page. In a browser, data file will be decompressed into memory to an uncompressed state. In any case, this file size is very large. You need to separate it with [asset bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) or [addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.addressables.html).

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake with the maximum memory size per page, because [Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-memory.html) says about 2 GB in HEAP

Comment: @stazik "Game.data" file size is 686MB. if we upload uncompressed build its loading but if we enable compression(br/gzip) the build loading fails with the above error in the browser.